# gridview's javascript return wrong value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

on my popup page i have a gridview, when client clicks a row it sends the datakey to the parent page

with this javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Done(val) {
        window.returnValue = val;
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

i put a break point on javascript code , when i click the row , i see that gridview sends the true value such as Done(02002) , i see that on my griview

but when i look at the script val = 1026 how this could be happening there is even no value such as 1026 on my page
thats how i add the javascript to my gridview

```
protected void grdSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
       if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
       {
           //string dd = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
          // ((Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnSec")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "Done(" >+ e.Row.Cells[0].Text + ")");
           e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Done(" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + ")");
           e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", >"this.style.backgroundColor='#3f529c';this.style.color='#FFFFFF';this.style.cursor='pointe>r';");
           e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", >"this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';this.style.color='#3f529c'; ");
           string dd = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
       }
 }
```

Comment: send the code where you received val = 1026

Comment: You have several strange right angle brackets for instance in `cursor='pointe>r'` or `Done(" >+ e.Row.Cells[0].Text` or `, >"this.style.backgroundColor`.